# Splitting first element on last space for lists of lists

Tags: python

I have a list of lists that look something like this:

```
data = [["first m. last", "info", "info", "info"],["first last", 
"info", "info", "info"]...]
```

I want to split out last names from each list into their own string in each list.

My idea was to create a list comprehension while using split() and finding the last space in the string (-1). I feel that I'm on the right track, but I don't understand where I'm going wrong.

```
dataNew = [row[0].split(" ", -1)[0] for row in data]
```

Actual output:

```
["firstname", "firstname", "firstname", ...]
```

Expected output:

```
dataNew = [["first m.", "last", "info", "info", "info"], ["first", 
"last", "last", "info", "info", "info"]...]
```

Your guidance is much appreciated! I also can't use Pandas for this.

Comment: Are the strings with more than one word always in the first position?

Comment: The lists are organized in the same way -- full names are in the first string in each list. I'm just trying to break out the last name from each string which is always separated by a space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did everything nearly right:

```
data = [
    ["first m. last", "info", "info", "info"],
    ["first last", "info", "info", "info"]
]

print([d[0].rsplit(' ', 1) + d[1:] for d in data])
```

> ```
> [['first m.', 'last', 'info', 'info', 'info'],
>  ['first', 'last', 'info', 'info', 'info']]
> ```

P.S. [rsplit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=rsplit#str.rsplit)